# Retrieve colour of diagram from sparx systems enterprise architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

[image]

Consider a below Image that is drawn in sparx systems enterprise architect tool is there any way to get the colour of each element like: blue, yellow. I know I cant get from tagged value because I have not mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Check `EA.DiagramObject.Style`

From the help file:

> The Style attribute is used for setting the appearance of a DiagramObject; it is set with a string value in the format:
>
> BCol=n;BFol=n;LCol=n;LWth=n;
>
> where:
>
> · BCol = Background Color
>
> · BFol = Font Color
>
> · LCol = Line Color
>
> · LWth = Line Width
>
> The color value is a decimal representation of the hex RGB value, where Red=FF, Green=FF00 and Blue=FF0000
>
> DiagObj.Style = "BCol=35723;BFol=9342520;LCol=9342520;LWth=1;"
>
> The following code snippet shows how you might change the style settings for all of the objects in the current diagram, in this case changing everything to red:
>
> ```
>      For Each aDiagObj In aDiag.DiagramObjects
>
>        aDiagObj.Style = "BCol=255;BFol=9342520;LCol=9342520;LWth=1;"
>
>        aDiagObj.Update
>
>        aRepos.ReloadDiagram aDiagObj.DiagramID
>
>      Next
> ```

Comment: The answer was very use full for me. Is it possible to get only "BCol". and my answer is something like this DUID=7B76C627;NSL=0;font=Arial;bold=0;italic=0;ul=0;charset=0;pitch=34;fontsz=80;BCol=16764057;

Comment: and how do you know which colours are those numbers?

Comment: But I am not able to understand the colour code actually . If BCol=16764057 could you tell me which colour is this? and how?

Comment: I think you saw the above diagram the Bcol for request one should Blue but its showing me the output as Pink-beige.